# Getting a UserId into a SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, parameters, insert, detailsview, userid

I am still new to asp.net and I'm having a problem that I just can't figure out.
I'm using vb and the .net membership api.

My question is, how do I get the current user's userid into a DetailsView INSERT?

```
<InsertParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="UserID"/>
</InsertParameters>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `OnInserting` event of your `SqlDataSource` you can retrieve the `UserID` from the Membership table by using the `ProviderUserKey` property of the `MembershipUser` class. You can then programmatically assign this value to the UserID insert parameter.

```
protected void SqlDataSource_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) 
{      
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();      
    Guid id = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
    e.Command.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = id; 
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly (after converting it to vb).  Thank you sooooooo much!  I was really close to that solution, just couldn't get it.  Thanks Phaedrus, you rock!  Wooo Hooo!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

User.Identity.Name will get you the unique user name. You can find the id in the aspnet_Users table.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this in one line:

```
protected void Sql_OnInserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
}
```